# Unable to import a project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not able to add a project in eclipse. I am adding the file location in the import wizard in the "archived file" section and **the finish button does not show up**.

The files are zipped.

I already have seven files imported in my eclipse 3.2.1. Is this the reason for the problem I am experiencing?

I have previously not imported those files into eclipse.

The problem arises only for some specific projects while I can easily import others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Import > "Existing Project into Workspace" feature is suited to import projects which are already configured for Eclipse. In this case, these projects should already have a .project file.

On the other hand, the Import > "Archive File" and "File System" options only import a directory or an archive content into a folder of a project that already resides in Eclipse Workspace.

Which one is the case?

If what you want to do is to import an archived file as though it were a project, then what you have to do is:

1. Create a blank new project in Eclipse.
2. Import the archived file into the new project base dir.
3. Configure the imported content appropriately (i.e. define source directory and other proper configurations).

For additional information, please refer to [Eclipse Online Help](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-70.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is also occurring on the 3.2.3 version of Appcelerator's Titanium Studio, so the problem must be in Eclipse - maddening! I haven't found a workaround other than creating a new blank project and then copying everything back into it.

Comment: problem being reproduced in Silabs Simplicity Studio (Eclipse based one)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether that archive files are eclipse projects or not??? 
Once the these links to import a project

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GFS/howto+import+project+into+eclipse

http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/